# Android for Cars - How to tell if the car is parked?

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

So far I found a [ParkedOnlyOnClickListener](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/androidx/car/app/model/ParkedOnlyOnClickListener?hl=zh-cn) that is triggered when the car is parked. But how can I query directly to see if the car is parked at the moment or not?

Alternatively, is there a way to tell if the engine is on or off?

I know there is a [speed API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/hardware/info/CarInfo#addSpeedListener(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.car.app.hardware.common.OnCarDataAvailableListener%3Candroidx.car.app.hardware.info.Speed%3E)), but this is not good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Automotive Apps you can use [CarPropertyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/hardware/property/CarPropertyManager) and use VehiclePropertyIds to get the current gear selection

// Values are taken from android.car.hardware.CarSensorEvent class.

```
    private val VEHICLE_GEARS = mapOf(
        0x0000 to GEAR_UNKNOWN,
        0x0001 to "GEAR_NEUTRAL",
        0x0002 to "GEAR_REVERSE",
        0x0004 to "GEAR_PARK",
        0x0008 to "GEAR_DRIVE"
    )
```

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/VehiclePropertyIds#GEAR_SELECTION](https://gear%20Selection)

Please have a look at the google sample code for gear Selection [Sample Code](https://github.com/android/car-samples/tree/main/car-lib/CarGearViewerKotlin)